# Table-cell doesn't fit its content

Tags: css, css-tables

I have table with CSS and structure:

```css
table, td {
 border: 3px solid #208000;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-size: 75%;
}
.headingTable {
 text-align: center; 
 padding: 1%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  table, td {
 border: 3px solid #208000;
 font-size: 100%;
  }
  .headingTable {
 font-size: 100%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
  table, td {
      border: 5px solid #208000;
  }
  .headingTable {
      font-size: 125%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <caption>Table caption</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class = "headingTable">First</td>
            <td class = "headingTable">Second</td>
            <td class = "headingTable">Third</td>
            <td class = "headingTable">Fourth</td>
            <td class = "headingTable">Fifth</td>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>     
        <tr>
            <td class = "headingTable">1</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
            <td>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pulvinar maximus massa, id sollicitudin urna iaculis sit amet. </td>
            <td>Mauris tincidunt augue erat, ac </td>
            <td> accumsan justo volutpat id</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Due to class headingTable the text of thead and first column are increased by 25% font-size at screen width wider than 1200px.
And at this screen width the first cell in thead doesn't fit to it's content ("First").
First column includes only one-digit numbers, therefore they don't overflow borders of their cells.
Also I have to mention that table contains about 40 rows.
So, the question is what I can do to make first cell in thead fit its content?

Comment: `padding: 1%;` remove this and check it out

Comment: @Dherya but then in other th there will be no padding.

Comment: Yes 
  `.headingTable {
 text-align: left;}`

Comment: smaller font and no padding? `thead tr .headingTable:first-child { ... `

Comment: @Dherya You're right! 'padding: 1% 0;' correct the thing! 
But maybe you know the cause of it? What is mechanism of such overflow? Why does it happen only with 'font-size: 125%'?

Comment: @Aleks Sid but "padding: 1% 0;" removes horizontal padding, so that solves nothing. The problem makes only padding in %, not font size.

Comment: @AlesTrunda I mean that there is no overflow at `font-size: 100%; padding: 1%`. But horizontal overflow occurs at `font-size: 125%`. And @Dherya way corrects this.

Comment: @AleksSid No there is no problem in `font-size:125%` no matter how much bigger you make it. The problem is with the padding because `padding : 1%` means giving padding to every area that means it will neglect the behavior of table cell and increase it's inside space from every side.  Below is the the solution for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem `<td><div class = "headingTable"> First</div></td>`

```css
table, td {
 border: 3px solid #208000;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-size: 75%;
}
.headingTable {
 text-align: center; 
 padding: 1%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  table, td {
 border: 3px solid #208000;
 font-size: 100%;
  }
  .headingTable {
 font-size: 100%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
  table, td {
      border: 5px solid #208000;
  }
  .headingTable {
      font-size: 125%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <caption>Table caption</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><div class = "headingTable"> First</div></td>
            <td class = "headingTable">Second</td>
            <td class = "headingTable">Third</td>
            <td class = "headingTable">Fourth</td>
            <td class = "headingTable">Fifth</td>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>     
        <tr>
            <td class = "headingTable">1</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
            <td>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pulvinar maximus massa, id sollicitudin urna iaculis sit amet. </td>
            <td>Mauris tincidunt augue erat, ac </td>
            <td> accumsan justo volutpat id</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! It also works! As well as mentioned by you `padding: 0;`.

Comment: good, but not 100% solution - you're getting padding from "div" width, but the original code gets padding form "table" width

Answer (score 0):

As @Dherya suggested, removing the `padding` of `.headingTable` solves the problem. Now, the reason why you had an overflow was that when the DOM calculated the width of the header `padding-left + "First" + padding-right`, it was more than the width of the cell `padding-left + "1" + padding-right`  below. So, it had to overflow. (Note that here the widest cell in a column is what sets the width of the header.)

Comment: So, you mean the cause is that cells in the column below header cell establish width of the column?

Comment: Yes, I do. For proof, try this with your initial code: add more text to the "1" cell (e.g lorem ipsum text). You will find that instead of the header, it is the cell that will now overflow. So, this case and the initial case you had are both solved by removing the `padding` on `.headingTable`.

Comment: You're definitely right! I've tried and everything as you told. Thank you for explanation!